# How to make this open a webbrowser inside a new form

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (domainUpDown2.Text == "Battlefield: Bad Company 2")
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

All that does is open a new blank form, but i need it to open a new form with a webbrowser in it so i can set it url dependent on the if statement..

Comment: And Form2 (should be renamed) has a WebBrowser control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your form2 has a WebBrowser control, and that it has a property you can set like this:

```
    public Uri WebLocation
    {
        set { webBrowser1.Url = value; }
    }
```

Then modify your code as follows:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    if (domainUpDown2.Text == "Battlefield: Bad Company 2")
        form2.WebLocation = new Uri("http://badcompany2.yoursite.com");
    if (domainUpDown2.Text == "Some Other Item")
        form2.WebLocation = new Uri("http://someotheritem.yoursite.com");
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```